If $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ exists (finitely or infinitely) then, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{2n}$ exists(finitely or infinitely).

Fact:"If limit of a real sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ exists then the limit of all subsequences of $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ exist and is equal to the limit of the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$."


Question:Does the same hold in the case of a series,in the sense that "If $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ is a series of real numbers whose sum exists finitely or infinitely,then can we say that the sum $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{2n}$ exists finitely or infinitely?

I tried it by considering the sequence of partial sums of the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{2n}$,in a hope that I can apply the above fact,but as the sequence of partial sums of the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{2n}$ is not subsequence of the sequence of the partial sums of the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ hence the above fact can not be applied.
The above statement may or my not be true.
Kindly someone help me.

Consider $1-1+1/2-1/2+1/3-1/3 + 1/4-1/4 + \cdots$.

@MartinR that's not a counterexample, since both sums exist (albeit one is infinite).

@MartinR thank you for your reply but as pointed above that both sums exist ,it does not contradict my statement.

@SandeepTiwari: You can easily modify that example. Start with any series $\sum b_n$ which does not converge, but $b_n \to 0$. Then consider $b_1 -b_1 + b_2-b_2 + b_3-b_3 + \cdots$.

@MartinR I will try.Thank you.

Consider $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} -\frac{1}{4}$ which converges to $ln2$ but the sum of the even terms would not converge.

This is not true, e.g. take $a_n=-1$ if $n$ is a multiple of $4$ and $a_n=1$ otherwise. Then $\sum a_n=\infty$ but $\sum a_{2n}$ does not exist.
For a counterexample where the first sum is finite but the second DNE, construct a sequence as follows. The terms are divided into blocks of four. The $k$th block all have absolute value $1/k$, and the odd terms in each block have one sign and the even terms have another. This ensures the sum of the sequence is $0$. Now you can choose the signs in each block to make the sum of even terms first climb above $1$, then below $0$, then above $1$, and so on.

Thank you for your answer.Sir,the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ to infinity is not clear ,kindly give some hint.

@SandeepTiwari The sum up to $N$ is between $N/2-1$ and $N/2+1/2$ for every $N$, so tends to $\infty$.

Got it.Thank you.
